# Crystal Reports for .NET within Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, advantage-database-server

I receive the following error when attempting to connect to a Sybase Advantage Database from  the Crystal Reports for .NET Framework within within Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012:

**Error 6414: Connection forcefully refused. axServerConnect**

I have attempted multiple driver versions and have settled on Version 11.1 for the framework.

I believe the database is version 11.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the Advantage Database Server version that you are trying to connect to?  I think that error can occur if you are trying to connect to an older server (a client cannot connect to an older server, although that, unfortunately, is not a very good error for that situation).

Comment: @MarkWilkins Thanks for the quick response. The Server version I am using is 11. I have uninstalled 11.1 framework and installed 10.1 I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

From the given information I cannot be sure what the problem is, but here are some things you can check.

- The obvious one is to make sure the server is actually running. I only mention this for completeness. If you try to make a TCP/IP connection to Advantage and it is not running, I believe the client will get a 6414.
- Verify that you are using the correct port number. If you specify it in the connection path, for example, verify that it is correct (the default port is 6262). Note that if you are using an ads.ini file, the port number could be specified in that file.
- Make sure the firewall on the server (or any firewalls in between) allow incoming TCP connections on port 6262 (assuming the default port is in use).

For debugging purposes, you might install [Advantage Data Architect](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=20&Release=19&Product=8&Platform=6) on the client and try making a connection from that utility. It might provide a simpler environment in which to debug the connection problem.

**Edit** Based on the comment about the non-default port number and the fact that it works with the other utility makes it sound like ads.ini file is not being found by Crystal Reports. Or, quite possibly, it is finding a different/wrong version of ads.ini. You could use [Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to determine exactly where the ads.ini file is being loaded from. Alternatively, you might add the port number to the connection path (`\\server:port\path`) to avoid the problem.

Comment: Server is confirmed to be running. I am using an ads.ini file with a specified port other than the default as the server is configured in that fashion. Firewall is allowing these connections on the proper port. I can connect and interact with the tables in this data source with the Architect. Thanks for all your input. Any other ideas?